# Can't boot Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, live-usb

I've just made a bootable USB stick following this official how-to:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

But unfortunately, my Mac doesn't seem to recognise the USB stick. Oddly, the same live USB stick works on my Samsung Netbook...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

look here

[solution booting and installing on mac](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick)

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "doesn't recognize", you mean that the USB stick doesn't show up on the list of options to boot from?  Some Macs of a certain age and make cannot boot from USB, or may not do it via the "option-startup" method.  What type and model of Mac are you using?